# How do I make Excel 2011 to highlight cells with formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I remember that I was able to make Excel highlight cells containing formulas with a different color, making easier to distinguish between calculated cells and cells where I manually entered data.

I recently switched to Mac and now I'm not able to find the same option on Excel 2011.

Answer (score 1):

[There](http://excel.tips.net/Pages/T002766_Coloring_Cells_with_Formulas.html) are several different methods of highlighting cells with formulas.

> If you are using Excel 2007, follow these steps instead:
>
> Press Ctrl+F3. Excel displays the Name Manager dialog box.
>   Click New. Excel displays the New Name dialog box.
>   In the Name field (at the top of the dialog box), enter a name such as FormulaInCell.
>   In the Refers To field (at the bottom of the dialog box), enter the following:
>
> `=GET.CELL(48,INDIRECT("rc",FALSE))`
>
> Click OK. The New Name dialog box disappears, the Name Manager dialog box reappears, and the name you defined is listed in the dialog box.
>   Click Close.
>
> Now you can follow the techniques previously outlined for setting up the conditional formatting. The only difference is that the conditional format should check for the following formula, instead:
>
> `=FormulaInCell`

This works in Excel 2010 as well (file must be saved as .xlsm) and I think it should work on Mac as it has same conditional formatting capabilities and macro support.